# Proper flow when waiting for PRs

Tags: git, git-workflow

When we accept PRs to the main branch they are squashed to a single commit and the original branch is deleted.

I want to know what is the proper flow to start to work on a feature that is based on another while that other feature is waiting for the PR to be accepted.

Let's say the original feature branch is `feature-1` and the new one is `feature-2`. Naively, I created `feature-2` from `feature-1` then when `feature-1` was accepted to the main branch, the history looked like this (note this is just commit order, in term of time, the commits in `feature-2` were in parallel to the one in `main`):

```
main
* GGG some other commit
* FFF squash commit of feature-1
* EEE some other commit
|
|    feature-2
|      DDD commit in feature-2
|     / 
| feature-1
|  CCC commit in feature-1
|  BBB commit in feature-1
|/
* AAA commit
```

When `feature-1` was accepted to the main branch, and I tried to merge from the main branch, I got many conflicts on the changes made in `feature-1` (which existed in `feature-2`). Rebasing caused even more conflicts.

What is the proper way of work here? Is it to start `feature-2` from main and merge/rebase feature-1? Some sort of rebase command from main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to do that **but** you need to be careful **not** not include the commits of the original `feature-1` when rebasing.... so, you need to rebase like this:

```
git rebase --onto upstream/master <last-commit-of-feature-1-in-feature-2> feature2
```

The problem is that **before running the rebase** you have something like this:

```
* HHH Merge of feature-1 (main)
|\
| * GGG squash of feature-1
|/
| * FFF second commit feature 2 (feature-2)
| * EEE first commit feature 2
| * DDD second commit feature-1
| * CCC first commit feature-1
|/
* BBB second commit main
* AAA first commit main
```

So, if you run a plain rebase like this

```
git checkout feature-2
git rebase main
```

git would have to consider the last common ancestor between both branches, which is `BBB` and then start applying all the commits in `BBB..feature-2` on top of `main`. **Because you squashed**, git is **not** aware that `CCC` and `DDD` have already been applied on `main` and so it will try to apply them **separately** on top of `main`, hence **BOOM!!!!**.

So, you need to do this to come out unscathed:

```
git rebase --onto main DDD feature-2
```

Then you will get this:

```
* FFF' second commit feature-2 (feature-2)
* EEE' first commit feature-2
* HHH Merge of feature-1 (main)
|\
| * GGG squash of feature-1
|/
* BBB second commit main
* AAA first commit main
```

Comment: What do I do if between BBB and GGG there is a HHH commit (from another feature)?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide a chart in your question to understand the whole thing. You can get it easily with `git log --oneline --graph branch1 branch2 etc etc etc`.

Comment: I added a diagram. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Ok... from your chart: `git rebase --onto main CCC feature-2`. You could use `git rebase --onto main feature-1 feature-2` **if** your local `feature-1` branch is still pointing to `CCC`.

Comment: Somewhat related... If you often work multiple features ahead (so end up needing to move multiple branch tips when rebasing like this) AND if you have a recent git (2.38 or later), then the `--update-refs` option of `git rebase` can automate some of that.

Comment: that is correct, @hartbx thanks for bringing it up.